Unity C# Microsoft SQL Server
I would like to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server from within C# while using Unity (2022.3.25f1). According to the C# Pocket Reference, it seems I can connect to SQL Server with the code marked with ★ below.
However, I get an error with using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;. I resolved this by using NuGet in Visual Studio Community 2022 to install the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package. This eliminated the error in Visual Studio.
However, when I press the play button in Unity, I get the message

All compiler errors have to be fixed before you can enter play mode

Do you have any solutions for this issue?
Are there any other general methods for using SQL Server with Unity (2022.3.25f1)?
Ultimately, I want to access a database stored on my home NAS from both iOS and Android devices.
Thank you for your help.


Because you arent supposed to use the nuget package with unity. When i tried this a few years ago i found concise instructions which worked very well  normally however when it comes to games direct game to db connections are less common

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

Ultimately, I want to access a database stored on my home NAS from both iOS and Android devices. I don't think that the Microsoft.Data exists on these platforms ... what speaks against System.Data.SqlClient

In Unity development, using NuGet packages is generally not recommended for several reasons:

Compatibility Issues: Unity uses a specific version of the .NET runtime, which differs from the standard .NET framework. This can cause certain NuGet packages to not work correctly or require additional configuration.
Refer to compatibility of Unity and .NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/unity-scripting-upgrade
Package Management Conflicts: Unity has its own package management system (such as the Unity Package Manager). Introducing NuGet packages can lead to version conflicts or other unpredictable issues.

As for directly connecting to a database from within a game, this is uncommon in game development for several reasons:

Performance Considerations: Directly connecting to a database can affect game performance, especially with high concurrent access.
Security: Direct database connections expose database connection details, posing security risks.
Architecture Design: Typically, games interact with databases through a server. The game client sends requests to the server, which then processes them and interacts with the database. This approach is more in line with best practices for security and performance.

